# How long in advance should I arrive at Tromsø Airport on a busy morning?

Tags: air-travel, tromso, tos

For an early morning flight in a busy season, how long in advance should I arrive at [Tromsø Airport](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troms%C3%B8_Airport) in [Tromsø](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troms%C3%B8), [Norway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norway)? In detail, on 21 December there's a 6:55 flight (to [Gran Canaria](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gran_Canaria_Airport)). There are other flights at 5:30, 5:55, 6:00, 6:40 and 6:45 (all domestic), then mine at 6:55, then none until 8:15. The first airport bus arrives at 5:45 ([timetable 2012-10-28 – 2013-03-12](http://www.flybussen.no/kunde/flybussen/Filvedlegg/11/901Flybussen.pdf). According to my ticket, check-in closes 45 minutes prior to departure. I will have luggage to check. **Is a 5:45 arrival on a busy day at Tromsø airport on time to catch a 6:55 flight?**

Comment: At such a (relatively) small airport, in a country like Norway, I'm sure 1h 10min before is enough. (Can't back that with anything other than intuition though. :)

Comment: Well, if check-in closes 45 minutes before, I technically have 25 minutes only.

Comment: can you check in online for the flight? Do you have luggage to check? Both of these affect which lines you may have to deal with and what cutoffs apply to you.

Comment: 25 mins, yes; how much extra time do you need? :) I bet it takes you about 5 minutes to find the check-in counter. And once there, there's no way you can miss the flight, even if there happened to be some queue. But if you're worried, just take a cab and be there, say, 1.5 hours before.

Comment: I like the old way, 3 hours before the flight I am at the check-in counter, 5 minutes to finish, and the the remaining 2:55 hrs is to regret coming early...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So your flight is an international flight.

The airport is fairly small, with just 5-6 restaurants, has wifi and opens officially at 4.30am in the morning.

To make sure, I'd always check the advice of the airport's website itself.  In this case, the official [Tromsø Airport website](http://www.avinor.no/en/airport/tromso/baggageandcheckin) says:

> It is advised that you arrive at the airport in plenty of time. The
>   length of time prior to departure depends on the airline, so remember
>   to check what time that applies to you. The usual attendance times
>   are.
>
> ```
> Domestic flights: at least one hour before departure
>
> International flights: at least one and a half hours before departure
>
> Charter flights: at least two hours before departure
> ```

On that advice, I'd try and get there at least a bit earlier - but would consider risking it if it was me.  But understand that if you are late and weren't there 90 min beforehand, the airline is not likely to be sympathetic :(